# detect elements not in single row and rearrange

Tags: jquery, css

I use ng-repeat(Angular JS) to create a set of buttons in a project, which i assumed to have max text length, so that all buttons will be in one single row.
(for example 1 row x 4 buttons)

if any one button is with additional content, then the last button is moved to the next line. so i get (1 row x 3 buttons && 1 row x 1 button)

In this case, i  want to realign the buttons as 2 rows x 2 buttons. How can i detect that buttons are breaking up to next line?

I got jquery in my project. So no issues if the solution is with jquery too.

Here is the sample [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/gj5mqwo0/) link

```
    <h4>Coded Output</h4>
<button>Hello World</button>
<button>Hello World</button>
<button>Hello World</button>
<button>Hello World</button>
<br>
<br>
<h4>Actual Output</h4>
<button>Hello World</button>
<button>Hello World -  Addln Content</button>
<button>Hello World</button>
<button>Hello World</button>

<h4>Expected Output</h4>
<div class="expected">
<button>Hello World</button>
<button>Hello World -  Addln Content</button>
<button>Hello World</button>
<button>Hello World</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 button{
  min-width:130px;
  height:40px
}

.expected button{
  min-width:200px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is to have an "orphan" button, you can use a [flex container](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) obtaining a single row of buttons, even when content is "too much" for a button (text flows inside the button). Check [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fazen/7m8k37x6/3/).
Check [browser's support and issues of the flex method](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex).

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <button>Hello World</button>
    ...
    <button>Hello World</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container { 
  display: -webkit-flex; 
  display: flex; 
  -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap; 
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
.container button { 
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto; 
  flex: 1 1 auto; 

  /* fix original css rules to let button's height changes */
  min-height: 40px;
  height: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [`.offset()`](https://api.jquery.com/offset/#offset1) or [`.position()`](https://api.jquery.com/position/) to determine the location of these elements, and compare the "top" values to see how many rows your elements span.

It would be somewhat easier if each button group were inside a wrapper element, like you did with `div.expected`

```
<div id="actual">
  <h4>Actual Output</h4>
  <button>Hello World</button>
  <button>Hello World -  Addln Content</button>
  <button>Hello World</button>
  <button>Hello World</button>
</div>
```

The javascript (wrapped in a dom load handler) simply counts the number of rows and then injects a `<br/>` after the 2nd element if needed. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gj5mqwo0/2/)

```
$(function () {
  var rows = 0,
      last = null;
  $('#actual button').each(function () {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    if(last !== offset.top) {
      rows++;
    }
    last = offset.top;
  });

  // Note this is hard-coded for 2 lines, and adds a line break after
  // the 2nd element, but you can change as needed to work in general
  if(rows === 2) {
    $('#actual').addClass('two-lines');
    $('#actual button:eq(1)').after('<br/>');
  }
});
```